# How to use Netty from inside a web app - steps to proper configuration

Tags: java, spring, web-applications, netty

I'm trying to setup [Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) to run embedded in my web application.

I have found the following document: http://docs.jboss.org/netty/3.2/api/org/jboss/netty/channel/socket/http/package-summary.html#package_description that describes how to configure a web.xml file that starts a Netty servlet.

Now the document says:

> Second, you have to bind your
>   Netty-based server application in the
>   same Servlet context or shared class
>   loader space using the local transport
>   (see LocalServerChannelFactory.) You
>   can use your favorite IoC framework
>   such as JBoss Microcontainer, Guice,
>   and Spring to do this. The following
>   example shows how to bind an echo
>   server to the endpoint specifed above
>   (web.xml) in JBossAS 5:

That sound reasonable but it is not clear to me how - *practically* - that should work. Say that I want to use Spring as Ioc container, what would be the proper beans configuration to bind netty to the local transport?

Also, how do I start the Spring context? From web.xml?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I personally recommend using spring. It can integrate with almost everything under the sun.

Take a look at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758970/using-java-nio-framework-in-spring-server/5778212#5778212) which shows how to configure your Netty server as a spring bean and then using it in a web app.

This is the way you could do it for a spring + web app.

```
1) Create relevant spring beans for the server, pipeline factory etc.
2) In the web.xml configure the spring dispatcher servlet.
```

**Note**: The above configuration is for running the Netty server at some port along with your web app.

Basically you can call the spring bean init-method attribute on any bean to do the netty server startup

You could configure the servlet as mentioned in the link in your post. You can cross-reference any spring bean(say the netty server bean) within the servlet bean, or call it within your servlet bean's init-method.

Yet another possibility is that you can listen to spring application events and then after the container has started up, you can manually launch your servlet/netty server.

If you are using a grails app then the bootstrap class ( a convenience class which is called on application startup) can be used to startup the Netty server on web app startup

Spring provides n-number of ways to do what you require, you can choose based on your convenience.