# Configure and embed Netty into Spring-Tomcat environment

Tags: spring, tomcat, websocket, netty

My question is similar to [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10674659/integrating-websockets-using-netty-with-spring-web-app-running-in-tomcat?rq=1).

I have a Spring application runs under tomcat on port 80. This is for RESTfull service and a web application.

Now new requirment comes in which is to use native Android clients (1000+) to exchange messages (events) from android app to the server, not android-to-android.
I'm not going to use same tomcat server to use HTTP for this messaging pipeline because,

1. Many android clients
2. Many messages/events will be there
3. Need a lighter protocol than HTTP

I though it is better to have a NIO socket server (ex: using websockets) such as Netty to handle only mobile client's messaging pipeline.
However these mobile clients  use RESTfull service as well.

**Message/event flows for Android clients**

```
Android ----> Netty ----> Spring App
```

**All the other request/response**

```
Android ----> Tomcat ----> Spring App
Web     ----> Tomcat ----> Spring App
```

They suppose to share the same authentication mechanism or separate mechanisms. However I have't though about that yet since no Netty is there.

I appreciate if anyone can give me directions, advice or sample configurations.

Answer (score 0):

You may embed Tomcat and Netty into spring application, making them to listen on different ports. Have a look at spring-boot project.

Tomcat supports websockets, may be you don't need the Netty.
Netty supports http codec, maybe you don't need the tomcat:)