# Configuring Netty with Spring IoC

Tags: netty

Has anyone used Spring to configure Netty?

I'm looking for an example or description on how I can configure Netty with Spring.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, you can. Look at the following [jet java game server](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server) written in Netty, the servers are all configured using spring. Take a look at the [server-beans.xml](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/master/jetserver/src/main/resources/jetserver/beans/server-beans.xml), [netty-handlers.xml](https://github.com/menacher/java-game-server/blob/master/jetserver/src/main/resources/jetserver/beans/netty-handlers.xml) etc in this project for reference.

For configuring Netty within a spring web-app look at the following [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5778212/596720).
**[Update]** Recently I have also [blogged](http://nerdronix.blogspot.com/2013/06/netty-4-configuration-using-spring-maven.html) about doing it with a java only configuration using no xml.

Answer (score 0):

Well Netty use just simple "pojos" so I see no problem here. Just create your bean definations as usual