# How to configure Netty Client Handler in Spring Web Application

Tags: json, spring, jsf, jsf-2, netty

Is there a specific way in configuring Netty Client Handler as a message receiving point in Spring JSF Web Application?

If some standalone Java applications act as Netty Servers How can I receive messages to the Spring JSF web application?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your question is how to configure netty with spring in a web application that uses JSF. If so, see this  link [Using JAVA NIO framework in SPRING server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3758970/using-java-nio-framework-in-spring-server/5778212#5778212).

Comment: It does not explain the data receiving part or any configuration related to it. And I do not know how those classes in the beans specified are coded. Basically what I want is how to retrieve the data to the web server, and if spring bean configurations are there for it what are they and the data retrieving code

Comment: For those look at Netty HTTP examples themselves. They are available at the https://netty.io/ home website