# Can twisted be implemented in Java?

Tags: java, python, asynchronous, twisted

I remember reading that the following features lead to the development of interesting frameworks/libraries in Python:-
(I read the article from http://www.python.org/workshops/2002-02/papers/09/index.htm)

1. A simple class model, which facilitates inheritance.
2. Dynamic typing, which means that the code needs to assume less.
3. Built-in memory management.

Java is statically compiled, and it has a garbage collector too. I wonder if its class model can be termed simple, however, keeping in mind the above mentioned points I have the following doubts:-

- Does Java has a Twisted analogue in Python(which is just as powerful)?

Answer (score 6):

[Netty](http://www.jboss.org/netty) is an event-driven networking framework written in Java, so it would most likely be Twisted's equivalent. The features are relatively similar to Twisted, and it seems powerful (I don't have any firsthand experience). It seems like it is still actively maintained. You'd have to look into it yourself to really get an idea of whether or not it meets your requirements.

Answer (score 3):

[Apache Mina v2.0](http://mina.apache.org/) is similar to Twisted.

Comment: Which one is more recommended? Mina or Netty?

Comment: I have worked with Mina only - so I cannot compare with Netty yet.

Comment: @jpartogi: Check this one - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637752/netty-vs-apache-mina

Answer (score 2):

There is one built for an openTSDB application. API is similar to python twisted. 
http://tsunanet.net/~tsuna/async/1.0/com/stumbleupon/async/