# Best framework for java networking programming?

Tags: swing, network-programming, netty, apache-mina

I am a newbie in java networking and I have a small project which i want to download on a LAN network and be used by just five users.

I want to use Java swing, MySQL for database and eclipse as IDE. 
So what is the best framework to make network programming easier cause i don't want to start from the scratch.

I read about Netty and Apache Mina, and i don't know if it's good for me in my case.

Answer (score 4):

see the [netty-vs-mina](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637752/netty-vs-apache-mina) link. Your question about "best" is not truly q&a format and should not be asked in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

This question is 5 1/2 years old, yet it has not been answered nor been closed. That's why i am writing this, asuming the questioneer meant a [Server-Client-Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Client%E2%80%93server_model).

---

I would recommend checking out [NetCom2](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/NetCom2). It's an easy to use framework, which maintains a high modularity for future improvements.

The concept behind this framework, might seem pretty odd, because it is build as an "over-network" [Event-Bus](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/EventBusExplained). The communication consists basically of objects, flying over the network and Servers/Clients reacting to it.

At the Server, you would write a java-programm, which might look like this:

```
public class ServerMain {

    private ServerStart serverStart;

    public ServerMain(int port) {
        serverStart = ServerStart.at(port);
    }

    public void start() throws StartFailedException, ClientConnectionFailedException {
        serverStart.launch();
        serverStart.acceptAllNextClients();
    }
}
```

And a potential Client would look like this:

```
public class ClientMain {

    private ClientStart clientStart;

    public ClientMain(String address, int port) {
        clientStart = ClientStart.at(adress, port);
    }

    public void start() throws StartFailedException {
        clientStart.launch();
    }
}
```

This is how you create and start a Server and a Client.
You can tell both the Client and the Server how to react to certain Objects. This should be done before [clientStart/serverStart].launch() by stating:

```
clientStart.getCommunicationRegistration()
           .register(MessageObject.class)
           .addFirst(messageObject -> System.out.println(messageObject));

serverStart.getCommunicationRegistration()
           .register(MessageObject.class)
           .addFirst((session, messageObject) -> session.send(messageObject));
```

Now you can send something from the Client to the Server, by stating:

```
clientStart.send(new MessageObject());
```

This example is basically an echo-server, which is explained [here](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/NetCom2/wiki/Example:-Echo-Server).
The communication between both in more detail can be found [here](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/NetCom2/wiki/Getting-Started) or [here](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/NetCom2/wiki/Communication).

If you are overwhelmed by the produced output, you can Regulate it by stating:

```
// Choose only one.
NetComLogging.setLogging(Logging.trace());
NetComLogging.setLogging(Logging.debug());
NetComLogging.setLogging(Logging.info());
NetComLogging.setLogging(Logging.warn());
NetComLogging.setLogging(Logging.error());
NetComLogging.setLogging(Logging.disabled());
```

Which is explained in more detail [here](https://github.com/ThorbenKuck/NetCom2/wiki/Decoubled-Logging).

---

## NOTINGS

Please note, that this project has just gone live and the documentation is still in progress.

Please also note, that this framework is still in beta. I would not recommend it for production use, but i would take a look at it for personal use.