# How to send a POJO from client to server using mina

Tags: java, apache-mina

I am very new to apache mina and I have a problem with sending a POJO from the client to the server. Please provide any sample code if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just starting with MINA you may want to consider whether you should actually be using Netty instead:

- [Netty vs Apache MINA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637752/netty-vs-apache-mina)

If you stick with MINA, there is a good quick start guide here with worked code examples:

- http://mina.apache.org/quick-start-guide.html

Comment: I've heard that Netty is more complicated than MINA is that true?

Comment: I actually heard the opposite :-) but probably the only way to find out is to do a quick prototype in both I guess. I found Netty fairly simple. YMMV. The other reason I previously went with Netty was the commercial backing of JBoss and what I perceived to be a stronger / more active community.