# Apache MINA vs netty for Android

Tags: android, netty, apache-mina

There is a very informative comparison between MINA and netty in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637752/netty-vs-apache-mina)
I would like to know your preference when the platform is Android!

- I have a *host* that should accept connections from as well as establish connections to android devices.
- This *host* implements Boost.ASIO for its operations. And I need to
  select an easy framework for the android side.
- Based on a couple of hours of googling, I, fairly new to java, narrowed to to **MINA** and **netty**. Both seem to be nice, though netty seemed to be easier.
- I got confused when i read a couple of bug reports about using netty in android.
- Number of android emulators connecting to the host can grow to a large number.

So the question is plain:
**which one is better to be used: netty or MINA?**

BTW,Any other framework to suggest?

I value you kind comments and answers. Thank you

Comment: You could write a native library in C++ using `Boost.Asio` (and cpp-netlib, if you need application-layer protocols http://www.cplusplus-soup.com/2011/08/cpp-netlib-091-released.html).

Comment: @IgorR. native library?! naaaaaah,  there should be better options out there. i am more comfortable with c++ but for this one, I really think I should use a java based solution. Let's concentrate on the main question: which one works better for android? netty or MINA.

Comment: This is an opinion question, which is discouraged. Both will likely work, and have different trade-offs. Pick one, and use it. Change to the other if you run into some brick wall you cannot get by.

Answer (score 0):

I opine like Jon Watte, this will be a "read and test", i have readed about both but seems no one is better than the other, just different, with his pros and cons.

Look for some project seemed like yours to get your task easier, if there are many projects on netty use this and viceversa with MINA.
So try which you prefer, just this.