# Netty performance comparison with other alternatives

Tags: netty

Is there a performance comparison between Netty 4 (or older version) against other alternatives such as Apache HTTPCore, Apache Mina etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't experienced MINA nor HTTPCore, but you can find different benchmark around like
http://wiki.apache.org/HttpComponents/HttpCoreBenchmark or report of lower perf for MINA here [Netty vs Apache MINA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1637752/netty-vs-apache-mina)

However, it seems that there is not such a huge difference in perf, whereas documentation, community activity, coding style etc. seem quite unequal. I would recommend to make a decision on those factors, as you will have difficulties finding a definitive answer as regards perf.

Answer (score 0):

We have benchmarked [Netty](http://netty.io) against [CoralReactor](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/category/coralreactor/) for a TCP client and server exchanging messages over loopback. The full results can be seen [here](http://www.coralblocks.com/index.php/2014/04/coralreactor-vs-netty-performance-comparison/) and the test basically consists of:

- The first JVM runs the client, the second JVM runs the server.
- The client connects to the server and sends a 256-byte message to the server.
- The first 8 bytes of the message is the timestamp marked by the client of when the message was sent.
- The server receives the message, reads the timestamp, reads the remaining 248 bytes and calculates the latency from client to server (one-way latency).
- The server then echoes back the message to the client.
- The client receives the echo and send the next message with a new timestamp.
- To warmup we send 1 million messages. Then we send another 1 million messages and benchmark the latencies.

We found that Netty performs with an average latency of **21.167 micros** per message while CoralReactor performs with an average latency of **2.061 micros** per message without producing any garbage for the GC.

Comment: Damn, those numbers are out of this world. What is the purpose of coralblock, what is mean to be used for?